# How to unload a DatePicker component so that it loads again with default values when page is re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-datepicker

I have a [single page application (singleSPA)](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/examples/) that has a [airbnb DatePicker](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/tree/master/examples) in the second page.

When I load the app for the first time, the DatePicker loads default startDate and endDate correctly.

However, when I come back to the first page and go to the second page again, the DatePicker retains the selected dates and does not reload to default values.

How do I get the DatePicker component to reset to default values when I come back to the second page ?

Comment: can you add a code sandbox ?